# When building a custom CentOS 7.6 iso I end up with an image that is unbootable from USB thumb drive

Tags: centos7, iso

balenaEtcher says my image file is not bootable and it's right. When I mkisofs I see what look like errors such as

```
Using ABRT_003.RPM;1 for  ./Packages/abrt-addon-xorg-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm (abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm)
Using ABRT_004.RPM;1 for  ./Packages/abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm (abrt-addon-pstoreoops-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm)
Using ABRT_005.RPM;1 for  ./Packages/abrt-addon-pstoreoops-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm (abrt-addon-python-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm)
Using 389_D000.RPM;1 for  ./Packages/389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm (389-ds-base-libs-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64.rpm)
```

This started happening today when I started using CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso. I'm pretty sure I was using CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810.iso and had an easy time building bootable isos.

Am I building using the wrong tool? mkisofs not good for DVD builds? Using

> mkisofs -o /tmp/656.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat
>   --no-emul-boot --boot-load-size 4 --boot-info-table -joliet-long  -R -V "RHEL-7.3\x20Server.x86_64" .

These builds finish without printing actual errors. /bin/file says 
"ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'RHEL-7.3\x20Server.x86_64' (bootable)" 
The iso is 4.3G.

I hate wasting DVDs so I'm writing to USB stick. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Those are not errors and not even relevant. That's just the Joliet/Rock Ridge junk from 25 years ago which isn't even used anymore but backward compatibility... Do you have actual errors?

Comment: No. 
The only error is that when I write the iso to thumb drive, it's not bootable.

Comment: If I don't change, add or remove rpms or edit the xml list of mandatory packages do I still need to run createrepo?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to boot from usb stick, you need to make it a CD/USB-Stick Hybrid image using `isohybrid`.
Just running `isohybrid <your-iso-image>.iso` should do the trick.